# Why Wappalyzer detects Wordpress and Elementor on my Site though I didn't use it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have been coding from Scratch using **HTML5, SCSS, JAVASCRIPT, JQUERY, JQUERY MIGRATE and PHP**. I have nowhere used Wordpress or any plugins of it. I have coded from sratch but after my development is completed, I created a a php file naming **site_dictonary.php**, where it contained all the functions which used to perform specific tasks, like inserting css or javascripts, calling particular ajax functions to send or receive data, connect with MySQLi, etc. I have divided the whole site into components like I have basically 6 simple components: **header, chest, abdomen, social-contacts, footer and feedback**. These components are contained in different php files and these files are called and encapsulated by **site_dictonary.php**. But I did not use Wordpress or Elementor anywhere. Then why Wappalyzer detects it to be a Wordpress site and detects only Wordpress and Elementor?
Can anyone explain this why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your site?

Comment: It is in my local environment

Comment: in that case - i can't help!